# Trouble with baking cylindrical objects

Tags: uv, normals, texture-baking

This is a half Blender/half XNormal question. I'm having difficulty with baking cylindrical surfaces. I'm trying to bake normals and occlusion for the twisted top edging of a wicker basket. Here is the high poly:

[image]

The low poly on top:

[image]

And the fantastic result:

[image]

How can I get a better bake with a shape like this?

I used the shrink wrap modifier which increased the vertex count too much and the result was equally awful:

[image]

Here is a link to a blend file with the shrink wrapped low poly model and the high poly twist model:

[image]

Comment: I do recommend you upload a portion of the .blend file for inspection. you can use this link to upload your file http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on that one. I've updated the post with the link.

Comment: Try using smooth shading on the low-poly object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this old method work for you ... using a prerendered hemisphere normal texture.

Basically I have attached a **shadeless** material of a normal rendering of a hemisphere. You will find the image packed in the blend file. Using a orthographic camera I render from the top view of the model. Also I have replaced the color of the background to a flat normal color which is (R0.5,G0.5,B1.0)

[image]

This is where you change the **background color** under the world tab on the
properties panel.

[image]

Hit the render button on the Render panel and you should get this result.

[image]

[image]

Let me know if you have further queries.